# VBA fills whole table instead of defined cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I ran into a crazy problem that I don't understand and for which I did not yet find a workaround.

First I have an excel macro filling various sheets on a workbook depending on information from other workbooks. I want to include a hyperlink to a website, containing the value in a specified cell in one workbook, while only displaying the value. I try to insert the formula as following

```
=HYPERLINK("https://example.com/value","value")
```

This hyperlink is only available for a certain cell, so it should only appear where a condition is true.
Now for the crazy part: If I fill the cell where I want to insert the hyperlink with a normal string or int, it works just fine and VBA only fills the cell I specified. When I insert a Hyperlink, it fills up the whole column on my worksheet, although everything else is kept in the same way.
Please find a snippet of the code below:

```
RequestID = Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text 'Request number

Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = RequestID
```

This only fills cell(y,4) with the correct request number as expected

```
Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = "RequestID"
```

This only fills cell(y,4) with the String "RequestID" as expected

```
  Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) &"https://example.com/" & RequestID & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & RequestID & Chr(34) & ")"
```

This fills up my whole table except for the header with the correctly working hyperlink.

I dont really understand why and I can't think of any possible problem. Maybe someone here has a hint for me, or knows a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked as expected for me when using a normal cell.  But when I tried it in a Formatted Table (aka ListObject) then it fill the entire column, because it is a formula and not a value.  If this is the case then try setting

`Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False`

before you put the Hyperlink in the cell (and then set it back to True)

Comment: Perfect, this works the way I expected it. I did not know this way pf work-around. Thank you very much!